# Javascript reg exp between closing tag to opening tag

Tags: javascript

How do I select with Regular Expression the text after the `</h2>` closing tag until the next `<h2>` opening tag

```
<h2>my title here</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <b>with more tags</b>
<h2>my title here</h2>
consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora
```

In this case I want to select this text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <b>with more tags</b>`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: That's not related to my question

Comment: It's exactly your question: you're trying to parse HTML with a regular expression. That can be done for a limited set of conditions, but will not work in general.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/<\/h2>(.*?)</g`

This finds a closing tag, then captures anything before a new opening tag.

in JS, you'd do this to get just the text:

```
substr = str.match(/<\/h2>(.*?)<h2/)[1];
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uH3wZ5/1)

```js
var str = '<h2>my title here</h2>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet<h2>my title here</h2>consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora';

var substr = str.match(/<\/h2>(.*?)<h2/)[1].replace(/<.*?>/g, '');

console.log(substr);
//returns: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null(…)

Comment: You will probably find that's because your string has breaks. Can you sanitise the string first?

Comment: I don't know what does it mean, I just need to select all the content until the closing </h2>

Comment: Updated with sample.

Comment: That's not working right, because If I have inside of the content other tag, for example: Lorem ipsum <b>strong tag</b> it will end right after the <b> tag

Comment: That wasn't clear in the original question - fixed in the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/<\/h2>((?:\s|.)*)<h2/
```

And you can see it in action [on this regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/oP3iO0/3).

You can see it in this example below too.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var inString, regEx, res, outEl;

  outEl = document.getElementById("output");

  inString = "<h2>my title here</h2>\n" +
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <b>with more tags</b>\n" +
    "<h2> my title here </h2>\n" +
    "consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora"

  regEx = /<\/h2>((?:\s|.)*)<h2/

  res = regEx.exec(inString);

  console.log(res);
  res.slice(1).forEach(function(match) {
    var newEl = document.createElement("pre");
    newEl.innerHTML = match.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    outEl.appendChild(newEl);
  });
}());
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="output"></div>
</main>
```

I added `\n` to your example to simulate new lines.  No idea why you aren't just selecting the `<h2>` with a `querySelector()` and getting the text that way.

Comment: But I want it without selecting the <h2> tags

Comment: @user4571629 Try now, use a capture group

Comment: That's not selecting anything, am I missing something? can you give me an example with console.log like on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Match the tags and remove them, by using string `replace()` function. Also this proposed solution `removes any single closure tags like <br/>,<hr/>` etc

```js
var htmlToParse = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].innerHTML;

var htmlToParse = htmlToParse.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,""); // clean up the multiLine HTML string into singleline

var selectedRangeString =  htmlToParse.match(/(<h2>.+<h2>)/g); //match the string between the h2 tags

var parsedString = selectedRangeString[0].replace(/((<\w+>(.*?)<\/\w+>)|<.*?>)/g, ""); //removes all the tags and string within it, Also single tags like <br/> <hr/> are also removed

document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].innerHTML += parsedString;
```

```html
<div class='input'>
    <i>Input</i>

  <h2>my title here</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br/> <b>with more tags</b>
<hr/>
  <h2>my title here</h2>
  consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora
</div>

<hr/>
<div class='output'>
  <i>Output</i>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Couple of things to remember in the code.

`htmlToParse.match(/(<h2>.+<h2>)/g);` returns an array of string, ie all the strings that was matched from this regex.

`selectedRangeString[0]` I am just using the first match for demo purspose. If you want to play with all the strings then you can just for loop it with the same logic.

Comment: That isn't what the OP asked for. Also, what happens if there's an element with no content, e.g. hr or input, in there?

Comment: ohhh I see the complexity now.. I will tweek my logic. Thanks @RobG

Comment: @RobG I fixed my code. Now this is what the OP asks for right?